# q-select selection is going outside of the input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

Here's my markup for the q-select

```
      <q-select
        square
        outlined
        fill-input
        standout="bg-grey-3 text-white"
        v-model="unit_selection"
        :options="units"
        options-dense
        dense
      >
      </q-select>
```

I noticed that I had some long options in my units,
so I just set this long value and the q-select just lets that text go way outside of the box.

`let units = ['aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa']`
[image]

Is there a way to shorten the length of the selected option so that it cuts it off so it doesn't go outside of the box?

Comment: I asked chatgpt and it said to use the wrap property and also to try a max-width, which I tried both and neither worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay figured it out, had to inspect element and found that this class
needs to hide its overflow

```
.q-field__native {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

honestly it should just be like this out of the box. Also
need to add a max width to the q-select otherwise the largest selected option
will just make the box huge.